# java netty message encoder/decoder no response

Tags: java, netty, encoder, decoder

I'm new to netty, and im trying to write a simple chat Client/Server application. If i'm using the default String encoder/decoder then everything works fine, but when i'm trying to write my own encoder/decoder it doesn't seem to send it to the server after the encoding. For the simplicity i'm trying to send just a constant integer now.

Heres the encoder:

```
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToByteEncoder;


public class ChatEncoder extends MessageToByteEncoder {

@Override
protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext chc, Object msg, ByteBuf out) throws Exception {
     System.out.println("ENCODE BEFORE");
     out.writeInt(2);
     System.out.println("ENCODE AFTER");
  }

}
```

Heres the decoder:

```
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder;
import java.util.List;


public class ChatDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder {

@Override
protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext chc, ByteBuf in, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("DECODE BEFORE");
    out.add(in.readBytes(4));
     System.out.println("DECODE AFTER");
  }

}
```

If i am using for the pipeline decoder/encoder these, then its not working. If i am using it  with the String encoder/decoder it works perfectly:

```
    pipeline.addLast("decoder", new ChatDecoder()); //StringEncoder()
    pipeline.addLast("encoder", new ChatEncoder()); //StringDecoder()
```

I get the "ENCODE BEFORE" and "ENCODE AFTER" message, but not the "DECODE BEFORE" one.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: please show how you invoke the write etc